# WARNING: More results were found in Get-SPSite but were not returned. Use 'Limit -ALL' when attempting to set credentials

Tags: powershell, docusignapi

When attempting to set the credentials on a SharePoint site with the DocuSign feature activated I get the warning:

"WARNING: More results were found in Get-SPSite but were not returned. Use 'Limit -ALL' to return all possible results."

The regex match will only iterate through 20 objects at a time, and I have around 60 sites. Where should I add "-Limit ALL' in the PowerShell so that it sill iterate through all my sites instead of just the top alphabetical 20?

```
Get-SPSite | ForEach-Object {
           if ( [RegEx]::IsMatch($_.Url, $regEx) ) {
              $url = $_.Url
              write-host "   $url"
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Limit ALL` parameter belongs with the [`Get-SPSite`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | ForEach-Object {
  ... iterate over each site ...
}
```

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607950.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You would add it to the Get-SPSite command, just like the error states.

```
Get-SPSite -Limit ALL | ForEach-Object {
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I marked Goyuix as the answer cause they beat you by a minute.